# Respond to individual touch events in javascript

Tags: javascript, iphone, webkit

Consider the scenario where a user touches the screen, holding the first finger down.  The user then taps the screen sequentially in two separate locations with a second finger.  I want to respond to this as three independent taps, and all I really care about are the initial tap locations.

I have tried using touchstart, but I can't figure out how to not reuse the first touch.  If I look for changes in the length of event.touches, I don't pick up the second (final) tap.

Can someone suggest a strategy for responding to each touch individually?  I am guessing it is quite simple, but I can't quite figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JQuery or Zepto [JQTouch](http://www.jqtouch.com/) is a good plugin that wraps up touch events nicely for you.  If you're interested in doing this at a lower level, you could always take a look at how they've done it.